# ESP8266 WebServer not responding (connection time out)

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, c++

My web server running on ESP8266, stop working after while.
I cannot connect to it - browser shows `connection time out` error.
No error, no crash... nothing.

Have you any idea how to fix it?

My code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <NTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#include <FS.h>

#include "console.h"
#include "tictactoe.h"
#include "main.h"

#define L_GREEN 2
#define L_YELLOW 0
#define L_ORANGE 4
#define L_RED 5

const char* ssid = "***";
const char* password = "***";

int requests = 0;
String IPs = "[";

IPAddress staticIP86_10(192,168,0,115);
IPAddress gateway86_10(192,168,0,1);
IPAddress subnet86_10(255,255,255,0);

ESP8266WebServer server(80); //Server on port 80

String getContentType(String filename);
bool handleFileRead(String path);

WiFiUDP ntpUDP;
NTPClient timeClient(ntpUDP, "1.sk.pool.ntp.org", 60*60, 60*1000);

//===============================================================
// Game Data
//===============================================================

/*String ticPlayer1 = "";
String ticPlayer2 = "";
String ticClick = "-1";
int ticReset = 0;*/

//===============================================================
// LEDs
//===============================================================
void LEDblink(int pin) {
  requests++;
  digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
}
//===============================================================
// This routine is executed when you open its IP in browser
//===============================================================
void handleNotFound(){
  if(server.uri().indexOf(".php")>-1) {
    Serial.print("404 "+server.uri()+": "+server.client().remoteIP().toString()+" (Blocked)\n");
    return;
  }
  Serial.print("404 "+server.uri()+": "+server.client().remoteIP().toString()+"\n");
  String s = HTML_Pro_notFound;
  server.send(404, "text/html", s);

  LEDblink(L_YELLOW);
}
void sendFile(String path, String type) {
  Serial.print(server.client().remoteIP().toString()+": "+server.uri()+"\n");
  if (SPIFFS.exists(path)) {                            // If the file exists
    File file = SPIFFS.open(path, "r");                 // Open it
    size_t sent = server.streamFile(file, type);        // And send it to the client
    file.close();                                       // Then close the file again
  }
}
//===============================================================
void reboot() {
 server.send(200, "text/plain", "true");
 LEDblink(L_RED);
 digitalWrite(15, LOW);
 digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
 ESP.restart();
}
void admin() {
 if(!server.hasArg("user") || !server.hasArg("pass") || server.arg("user") == NULL || server.arg("pass") == NULL || server.arg("request")=="login") {
    String expire = "";
    if(server.arg("remember")=="on"){expire="30";}else{expire="0";}
    server.send(200, "text/html", "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'><head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>ProTools.tk | Please Wait</title><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/main.css'><script src='/cookies.js'></script></head><body style='background:#2d2d2d'><form class='center' action='/admin' method='post' style='display:none;'><input class='a' type='text' name='user'><input class='a' type='password' name='pass'><input class='a' type='text' name='request' value='panel'><button class='a' type='submit'></button></form><div class='loading center' style='margin-top:150px'></div><script type='text/javascript'>var u = '"+server.arg("user")+"';var p = '"+server.arg("pass")+"';if(u.length > 7 && p.length > 7) {delCookie('user');delCookie('pass');setCookie('user', u, "+expire+");setCookie('pass', p, "+expire+");}if(getCookie('user') && getCookie('user')) {var a=document.getElementsByClassName('a');a[0].value=getCookie('user');a[1].value=getCookie('pass');a[3].click();}else{location.replace('/login');}</script></body></html>");
    //server.sendHeader("Location","/login");
    //server.send(303);
 }
 if((server.arg("user")=="***")&&(server.arg("pass")=="***")) {
   if(server.arg("request")=="data") {
     String c = "{\"uptime\":"+String(millis(),DEC)+",\"req\":"+String(requests)+",\"ips\":"+IPs+"]}";
     server.send(200, "text/json", c);
   }
   else if(server.arg("request")=="panel") {
     server.send(200, "text/plain", "Admin panel here");
   }
   else {
    server.send(400, "text/plain", "400 Bad Request");
   }
 }
 else{
   server.sendHeader("Location","/login");
   server.send(303);
 }
 LEDblink(L_RED);
}
void console() {
 Serial.print("Console :"+server.client().remoteIP().toString()+"\n");
 String s = HTML_console;
 server.send(200, "text/html", s);
 LEDblink(L_ORANGE);
}

//===============================================================
/*void minesPage() {
 String s = HTML_mines;
 server.send(200, "text/html", s);
 LEDblink(L_YELLOW);
}
void minesScript() {
 String s = JS_mines;
 server.send(200, "text/javascript", s);
 LEDblink(L_YELLOW);
}
void minesStyle() {
 String s = CSS_mines;
 server.send(200, "text/css", s);
 LEDblink(L_YELLOW);
}*/

//===============================================================

/*void ticPage() {
 String s = HTML_tictactoe;
 server.send(200, "text/html", s);
 LEDblink(L_YELLOW);
}
void ticScript() {
 String s = JS_tictactoe;
 server.send(200, "text/javascript", s);
 LEDblink(L_YELLOW);
}
void ticStyle() {
 String s = CSS_tictactoe;
 server.send(200, "text/css", s);
 LEDblink(L_YELLOW);
}

void ticData() {
 Serial.print("TicTacToe: "+server.client().remoteIP().toString()+"\n");
 String user = server.arg("user");
 String clicked = server.arg("click");
 String request = server.arg("request");
 String leave = server.arg("leave");
 if(user != "") {
  if(user == "get") {
   server.send(200, "text/plain", "{\"Player1\":\""+ticPlayer1+"\", \"Player2\":\""+ticPlayer2+"\"}");
  }
  else if(ticPlayer1 == "") {
   ticPlayer1 = user;
   server.send(200, "text/plain", "player1");
  }
  else if(ticPlayer2 == "") {
   ticPlayer2 = user;
   server.send(200, "text/plain", "player2");
  }
  else {
   server.send(200, "text/plain", "Full");
  }
  if(ticPlayer1 != "" && ticPlayer2 != "") {
   ticClick = "0";
  }
  digitalWrite(L_ORANGE,HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(L_ORANGE,LOW);
 }
 else if(leave != "") {
  if(leave == ticPlayer1) {
   ticPlayer1 = "";
  }
  else if(leave == ticPlayer2) {
   ticPlayer2 = "";
  }
  ticClick = "-1";
  server.send(200, "text/plain", leave+" left");
 }
 else if(clicked != "") {
  ticClick = clicked;
  server.send(200, "text/plain", "OK: "+ticClick);
 }
 else if(request != "") {
  if(request == "checkClicked") {
   server.send(200, "text/plain", ticClick);
  }
  if(request == "reset") {
   ticReset++;
   if(ticReset == 2) {
    ticPlayer1 = "";
    ticPlayer2 = "";
    ticClick = "-1";
    ticReset = 0;
    server.send(200, "text/plain", "Reseted");
   }
   else {
    server.send(200, "text/plain", "Verification required");
   }
  }
 }
 LEDblink(L_YELLOW);
}*/
//==============================================================
//                  SETUP
//==============================================================
void setup(void){
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //Onboard LED port Direction output
  pinMode(L_GREEN,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(L_YELLOW,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(L_ORANGE,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(L_RED,OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(L_RED, HIGH);

  WiFi.hostname("ESP8266");

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);     //Connect to your WiFi router

  MDNS.begin("ESP8266");
  MDNS.addService("http", "tcp", 80);

  digitalWrite(L_RED, LOW);
  // Wait for connection
  digitalWrite(L_ORANGE, HIGH);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  digitalWrite(L_ORANGE, LOW);
  digitalWrite(L_YELLOW, HIGH);

  WiFi.config(staticIP86_10, gateway86_10, subnet86_10);

  //If connection successful show IP address in serial monitor
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());  //IP address assigned to your ESP

  SPIFFS.begin();

  server.on("/", []() {                                          // root
    sendFile("/page.html", "text/html");
    LEDblink(L_YELLOW);
  });
  server.on("/main.css", []() {                                  // main.css
    sendFile("/main.css", "text/css");
    LEDblink(L_ORANGE);
  });
  server.on("/page.css", []() {                                  // page.css
    sendFile("/page.css", "text/css");
    LEDblink(L_ORANGE);
  });
  server.on("/page.js", []() {                                   // page.js
    sendFile("/page.js", "text/javascript");
    String ip = server.client().remoteIP().toString();
    if(IPs=="["){
      IPs+="{\"time\":"+String(timeClient.getEpochTime(),DEC)+",\"ip\":\""+ip+"\"}";
    }else{
      IPs+=",{\"time\":"+String(timeClient.getEpochTime(),DEC)+",\"ip\":\""+ip+"\"}";
    }
    LEDblink(L_YELLOW);
  });
  server.on("/login/style.css", []() {                           // login/style.css
    sendFile("/login/style.css", "text/css");
    LEDblink(L_ORANGE);
  });
  server.on("/cookies.js", []() {                                // cookies.js
    sendFile("/cookies.js", "text/javascript");
    LEDblink(L_ORANGE);
  });

  server.on("/translator", []() {                                // translator
    sendFile("/translator/page.html", "text/html");
    LEDblink(L_ORANGE);
  });
  server.on("/translator/style.css", []() {                      // translator/style.css
    sendFile("/translator/style.css", "text/css");
    LEDblink(L_ORANGE);
  });
  server.on("/translator/script.js", []() {                      // translator/script.js
    sendFile("/translator/script.js", "text/javascript");
    LEDblink(L_ORANGE);
  });

  server.on("/login", []() {                                     // login
    sendFile("/login/page.html", "text/html");
    LEDblink(L_ORANGE);
  });
  server.on("/admin", admin);
  server.on("/reboot", reboot);
  server.on("/console", console);

  /*server.on("/minesweeper", minesPage);
  server.on("/minesweeper/script.js", minesScript);
  server.on("/minesweeper/style.css", minesStyle);

  server.on("/tictactoe", ticPage);
  server.on("/tictactoe/script.js", ticScript);
  server.on("/tictactoe/style.css", ticStyle);
  server.on("/tictactoe/data", ticData);*/

  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);

  server.begin();                  //Start server
  timeClient.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
  digitalWrite(L_YELLOW, LOW);
  digitalWrite(L_GREEN, HIGH);
}
//==============================================================
//                     LOOP
//==============================================================
void loop(void){
  timeClient.update();
  server.handleClient();          //Handle client requests
}
```

Comment: what version of the esp8266 arduino package you use?

Comment: hmm... I am not sure what version do you mean but in Arduino Board Manager I have installed ESP8266 of version 2.0.0 Please specify more where I can find that version if this is not what are you want.

Comment: What mime type is `text/plane`? Are you trying to transfer an aircraft?

Comment: use the latest version 2.4.2

Comment: @Majenko oops :D thanks for warning! I wrote it wrong and copy it to whole code, but its works good xD

Comment: @Juraj Its looks like it working. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried resetting your esp8266 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the latest version of Arduino esp8266 core package (2.4.2 or higher).